# Auto populate form inputs with Laravel and Live Wire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

**Goal:** on focusout event I want to auto populate html input fields  #City #State (full name) #State2 (abbreviation) 
**Questions**
**1)** how do I get the input passed to the function?
**2)** What do I need to do to populate the fields?

in resouces\ **views:   locale.blade.php**

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="City" id="City" value="{{ $city }}">
<input type="text" name="State" id="State" value="{{ $state }}">
<input type="text" name="State2" id="State2" value="{{ $state2 }}">
<input type="text" name="Zip" id="Zip" value="{{ $zip }}"
       wire:focusout="setlocale">
</div>
```

in App\Http\ **LiveWire Locale.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\State;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class Locale extends Component
{
    public $zip = "";
    public $city = "";
    public $state = "";
    public $state2 = "";
    
    public function setlocale()

    {   
        $locale_arr=[];
        $g = $this->zip;
        dd($g);       ################## its only returning "" in my dd(); ###################
        $z = State::get()->where('zip',$g);
        $city = $z->city;
        $state = $z->state_name;
        $state2 = $z->state2_id;
        //TODO somehow render these variables in input fields.
        
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.locale');
    }
}
```

in App\Models\ ** State**

```
class State extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

}
```

**Tinker**

```
>>> use App\Models\State
>>> $a = State::get()->where('zip','10001');
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#70820
     all: [
       2569 => App\Models\State {#35131
         id: 2570,
         zip: "10001",
         lat: 40.7506,
         lng: -73.9972,
         city: "New York",
         state_id: "NY",
         state_name: "New York",
         county_name: null,
         timezone: null,
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: v-model https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html  and watch. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: @MichaelMano forgive my ignorance is vuejs part of live-wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Livewire, you have to bind the inputs to the properties of your class using `wire:model`. Livewire will then handle setting the value of your inputs to what you have in the component.

```html
<div>
   <input type="text" name="City" id="City" wire:model="city" />
   <input type="text" name="State" id="State" wire:model="state" />
   <input type="text" name="State2" id="State2" wire:model="state2" />
   <input type="text" name="Zip" id="Zip" wire:model="zip" wire:focusout="setlocale" />
</div>
```

Then, instead of using `wire:focusout`, I recommend that you use a lifecycle-hook in the PHP class instead. So remove `wire:focusout="setlocale"` from your HTML, and add the following to your PHP class,

```php
public function updated($field, $value) 
{
    if ($field === 'zip') {
        $this->setlocale();
    }

}

public function setlocale()
{   
    $zip = State::where('zip', $this->zip)->first();
    $this->city = $zip->city;
    $this->state = $zip->state_name;
    $this->state2 = $zip->state2_id;
}
```

Comment: @Quirel, the wire:model.lazy doesn´t accomplish this? Just a question ;-)

Comment: @Prospero The `.lazy` modifier makes the request fire when the user clicks away from the input, similar to `focosout`, but the point is that OP was missing `wire:model` entirely, and that its better to use the lifecycle hooks to run that `setlocale()` method, than using `wire:focusout`. The `.lazy` modifier may be applied here to make the request fire when clicking outside, no problem there.

Comment: @Qirel I got it working like you said. I removed focus out and used the ````wire:model.lazy="zip"```` but then i had to add a call to my render function with ````$this->render(); ```` but it works now thank you very MUCH!!!!!